# PHP - bindtextdomain stops working on certain pages of localised Website

Tags: php, gettext

I am hoping someone can help me with this issue. My website is localised into German, French, Spanish and English. Everything seems to work correctly but during testing and often sporadic, the localised text does not appear and except the string codes appear. The variable $language is been set correctly as the images are language specific and they are always displaying.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
// I18N support information here
putenv("LANG=" . $language); 
setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);

// Set the text domain as "messages"
$domain = "messages";
bindtextdomain($domain, "./locale"); 
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');

textdomain($domain);
```

The one thing I do seem to notices is this issue only occurs in pages of format:
http://example.com/product/product_name.php
It always works in pages of format http://example.com/page.php

Can anyone help or even give me details on how I could debug

Comment: You need to add more code. How, for instance, is text being called?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to ensure that your path to [bindtextdomain](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bindtextdomain.php) is correct. I would suggest this in your bootstrap file:

```
define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));
```

and then in your script

```
bindtextdomain($domain, ROOT_PATH . '/locale');
```

This way if you get into a subfolder such as `product/product_name.php` `bindtextdomain` will not try to find the `locale` folder in the `product` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Nikolaos! I had the same problem, and the solution is to use always absolute path inside 2nd parameter of bindtextdomain

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29959060)